# Cannot load RefTex

Tags: auctex, reftex

I try to automatically load `RefTeX` for all my `LaTeX` files. However, when I launch `Emacs` I get the following error:

> Error loading autoloads: (void-function defstruct)

What this error mean and how can I solve it?

(I suspect that this is the reason why `RefTeX` does not load automatically)

Comment: Does it mean that this happens if you start Emacs with an init file containing only this single line `(require 'reftex)`?

Comment: my `init` file has the following: `(require 'reftex)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)`

Comment: yes, it does....

Comment: Hmm, strange.  The only thing comes to my mind is to put `(require 'cl)` before `(require 'reftex)`.  I `grep`'ed over the `.el` files from RefTeX and I don't see a `defstruct`.  FWIW, it is a macro provided by `cl` library.  Do you get the error if you start Emacs with `emacs -q` and `emacs -Q`?

Comment: the problem remains if i use `(require 'cl)`, but it disappears if I start `Emacs` with `emacs -q` or `emacs -Q`

Comment: Having no problem with `emacs -q` indicates something strange in your init file.  My really last guess is that you start Emacs and do `M-x list-load-path-shadows RET`; maybe that output helps.

Comment: @ArashEsbati I did that and the output says "no emacs lisp load-path shadowing was found"...

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas `:-[`

Comment: no problem :)... I always can enable manually `reftex` once I open my `.tex` files :)